# Displaying spinning AJAX loader image

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, progress-bar, spinner, flex4.5

I would like to display a spinning image, when my application is not connected to the socket server and is in an "offline" state.

So I've tried using an ajax-loader.gif, courtesy of http://www.ajaxload.info/

[image]

```
<s:Image source="@Embed(source='assets/ajax-loader.gif')" 
   horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0" includeIn="offline" />
```

but unfortunately the bitmap is not animated (does not spin).

Is there a way to do that, how do you approach displaying a "loading indicator" in your Flex 4.5 programs?

Or do I have to fallback to [mx.controls.ProgressBar](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ProgressBar.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you embed a gif, only the first frame gets embedded.

You can either use an "swf" animation file that has a spinner and use it inside an `Image` tag or you can also check out gif libraries in as3, [as3 gif player](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=95) and [as3gif](http://code.google.com/p/as3gif/).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the progress bar set to in determinant ;)